# Django - get latest item from get_object_or_404

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to return an object from my `get_object_or_404` method but my query returns multiple objects. Is there a way to get last or first item?

This is how I do it:

```
return get_object_or_404(BatchLog, batch_id=self.kwargs["pk"])
```

I know it is not possible but this is kind of what I need:

```
return get_object_or_404(BatchLog, batch_id=self.kwargs["pk"].last())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As the documentation says](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404), you can use a `QuerySet` instance instead of the model's class.

This should work:

```py
return get_object_or_404(
    BatchLog.objects.order_by('-date')[:1],
    batch_id=self.kwargs["pk"],
)
```

Notice that we need to limit the `QuerySet` instead of using `.first()` or `.last()` that would give us the object.

But it may actually be better to do it manually:

```py
try:
    return BatchLog.objects.filter(batch_id=self.kwargs["pk"])[0]
except IndexError:
    raise Http404('No logs for this id')
```

Comment: both this and @Henri's answer makes sense and will probably work, but instead of getting a 404 a get a `BatchLog`object with empty or null fields

Comment: Oh, my bad. `first()` returns `None` instead of an error. Let me change that.

Answer (score 1):

`get_object_or_404` is equivalent to :

```
from django.http import Http404

def my_view(request):
    try:
        obj = MyModel.objects.get(pk=1)
    except MyModel.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("No MyModel matches the given query.")
```

In your case you could do :

```
    try:
        obj = MyModel.objects.filter(pk=1).last()
    except:
        raise Http404("No MyModel matches the given query.")
```

or better, if you have a way to order them:

```
    try:
        obj = MyModel.objects.order_by('date_created').filter(pk=1).last()
    except:
        raise Http404("No MyModel matches the given query.")
```